# loop through filtered collection in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I try to do things like this in my post:

```html
<ul class="articles-list">
  {% for post in site.posts | where:'group', post.group %}
    <div data-scroll-reveal="enter ease 0">
      {% include article-snippet.html %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but it loops through all my collection instead the only loops posts with special group.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot use where filter in a loop.

But you can do :

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:'group', post.group %}

<ul class="articles-list">
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div data-scroll-reveal="enter ease 0">
      {% include article-snippet.html %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I used this for subcategory table of contents in a versioned documentation site.  I chained two wheres together, first for version and then category. This allows me to put all the docs ina collection.

Comment: Is there a way to filter where `group` is *not* `post.group`?

Comment: `{% assign posts = site.posts | where_exp:"p", "p.group != post.group" %}`

Answer (score 4):

According to [liquid documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters) about filters they should be used inside output tags `{{` and `}}`.

You can maybe try an if statement:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.group == 'group' %}
        <div data-scroll-reveal="enter ease 0">
            {% include article-snippet.html %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you should use the where filter [a bit differently](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/). Something like this:

```
{{ site.members | where:"graduation_year","2014" }}
```

This says select site members whose graduation_year is 2014. You don't need to specify that it should filter members, the first part implicitly states that.